# iOS Swift: UIImage from Data is blurred

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uikit

in my app I display pictures from the user library.
They are saved in a **Core Data** cache and the presented in a **collection view** with an **UIImage**.

But sometimes they are blurred like in the following image:

[image]

The first 2 rows are images fetched from the user library, the last row are images fetched from the web (and they are in good quality). 
All the images are saved in core data.

This is the code where I convert the PHAsset into a raw data and than I save it into Core Data:

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil) { (image, info) in
     let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
     let file = MediaFile.newMediaFile(data: data, type: .image)
     localMedia.addMedia(media: file)
 }
```

and here I build the image with the raw data extracted from core data:

```
func buildImage(fromMedia localMedia: LocalMedia, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
        bgQueue.async {
            guard let file = localMedia.orderedMediaFiles.first,
                let data = file.data,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
            }
                completion(image)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Almost for sure you are getting an image somewhere that is much smaller than you think, and thus when you show it, its magnified and blurred. When you get the image from PHImageManager, log (ie print()) the image size. Add print statements when you read it, and when you show it, and log the size of the frame you show the image in. Somewhere you will find that the size isn't what you thought it was.

Comment: Look like you are using a background queue, so I would check very carefully that everything is being done on the correct thread: UI updates must be on main thread, CoreData activity must be done on correct queue for the context.